# Boxplot for Time Series Data

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, boxplot

Given this data set how would you go about generating the box plot in r.

```
"huron" <- 
structure(.Data = c(581.55999999999995, 581.54999999999995, 581.34000000000003, 580.84000000000003, 
    580.33000000000004, 580.35000000000002, 579.87, 580.49000000000001, 
    579.90999999999997, 580.07000000000005, 580.90999999999997, 581.10000000000002,
    579.72000000000003, 580.32000000000005, 580.48000000000002, 580.38, 
    581.86000000000001, 580.97000000000003, 580.79999999999995, 579.78999999999996,
    580.38999999999999, 580.41999999999996, 580.82000000000005, 581.39999999999998,
    581.32000000000005, 581.44000000000005, 581.67999999999995, 581.16999999999996,
    580.52999999999997, 580.00999999999999, 579.90999999999997, 579.13999999999999,
    579.15999999999997, 579.54999999999995, 579.66999999999996, 578.44000000000005,
    578.24000000000001, 579.10000000000002, 579.09000000000003, 579.35000000000002,
    578.82000000000005, 579.32000000000005, 579.00999999999999, 579., 
    579.79999999999995, 579.83000000000004, 579.72000000000003, 579.88999999999999,
    580.00999999999999, 579.37, 578.69000000000005, 578.19000000000005, 
    578.66999999999996, 579.54999999999995, 578.91999999999996, 578.09000000000003,
    579.37, 580.13, 580.13999999999999, 579.50999999999999, 579.24000000000001, 
    578.65999999999997, 578.86000000000001, 578.04999999999995, 577.78999999999996,
    576.75, 576.75, 577.82000000000005, 578.63999999999999, 580.58000000000004, 
    579.48000000000002, 577.38, 576.89999999999998, 576.94000000000005, 
    576.24000000000001, 576.84000000000003, 576.85000000000002, 576.89999999999998,
    577.78999999999996, 578.17999999999995, 577.50999999999999, 577.23000000000002,
    578.41999999999996, 579.61000000000001, 579.04999999999995, 579.25999999999999,
    579.22000000000003, 579.38, 579.10000000000002, 577.95000000000005, 578.12, 579.75,
    580.85000000000002, 580.40999999999997, 579.96000000000004, 579.61000000000001,
    578.75999999999999, 578.17999999999995, 577.21000000000004, 577.13, 
    579.10000000000002, 578.25, 577.90999999999997, 576.88999999999999, 
    575.96000000000004, 576.79999999999995, 577.67999999999995, 578.38, 
    578.51999999999998, 579.74000000000001, 579.30999999999995, 579.88999999999999,
    579.96000000000004, 580.98000000000002, 581.03999999999996, 580.49000000000001,
    580.51999999999998, 578.57000000000005, 578.96000000000004, 579.94000000000005,
    579.76999999999998, 579.44000000000005, 578.97000000000003, 580.08000000000004,
    580.23000000000002, 580.75, 581.26999999999998)
, class = c("ts", "numeric")
, tsp = c(1860., 1986., 1.)
, title = "Lake Huron, mean level, July, 1860-1986"
)
```

I don't know how to generate a Boxplot for this because I don't know what to assign as x and y.

Answer (score 1):

In base R we could just do like this:

```
boxplot(huron)
```

[image]

With `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)

#ts to dataframe
df <- data.frame(huron) 

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = "", y = huron)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]